# Doubt in Wilson's theorem

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

By Wilson's theorem, I have that $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$ for any odd prime $p$ which means that $p\mid (p-1)!+1$

But how does it reduce to that the remainder when $(p-1)!$ is divided by $p$ is equal to $p-1$?

Comment: $$p\mid -1+1=0 \Leftrightarrow p\mid (p-1)+1=p$$ Don't mix up "$\equiv$" and "$=$". "$a\equiv b \pmod p$" means $p\mid a-b$.

Comment: Your last sentence is too ungrammatical to be understood. Please edit.

Answer (score -2):

**hint**

$$p-1\equiv -1 \mod p$$

So, the remainder after a division by $ p $, won't be $ -1 $ but $ p-1$.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please give some details

Comment: I understood that p-1 $\equiv$ -1(modp)..But I didn't understand the next step

Comment: @Gitika The remainder is non negative. it could not be $-1$ but $ p-1$. Take an example.